# Show that R[0,1] is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let R[0,1] be the set of Riemann integrable functions between 0,1 by considering $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\chi _{[n^{-1},1]}(x)$ Where $\chi _{[n^{-1},1]}$ is the indicator function for if x is between $n^{-1},1$ with respect to the norm $\left \| f \right \|_1=\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x ) \right |dx$

**Edit:** 
I have to show this using the function $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\chi _{[n^{-1},1]}(x)$ so I don't think it's a duplicate since the other question is considering different functions and my issue is showing this function doesn't converge.

**Thoughts so far**

First I want to show that $f_{n}$ is Cauchy so I consider for $n>m$ $$\left \| f_{n
}-f_{m} \right \|_1=\int_{0}^{1/n} 0\,  dx+\int_{1/n}^{1/m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx +\int_{1/m}^{1} 0 \, dx  $$

I think this is Cauchy since as $n,m\rightarrow \infty $ then $1/n,1/m \rightarrow 0$ so $\left \| f_{n}-f_{m} \right \|_1 \rightarrow 0$ which is less than $\epsilon$   $ \forall$ $\epsilon >0$, But does this not imply $f_n$ converges to $0\in R[0,1]$

Edit: **New idea** Assume $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ then $\left \| f_{n}-f \right \|_1 < \epsilon $  for some $n>N\in \mathbb{N} $ and $\epsilon >0$ so $$\left \| f_{n}-f \right \|_1 =\int_{0}^{1/n} 0\,  dx+\int_{1/n}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx   $$

$\Rightarrow f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ when x is between $1/n$ and $1$ and 0 otherwise which is $\notin$R[0,1]

Comment: @StammeringMathematician  I have to show this using the function $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\chi _{[n^{-1},1]}(x)$ so I don't think it's a duplicate since the other question is considering different functions and my issue is showing this function doesn't converge.

Comment: Actually compute $\int 1/\sqrt{x}$, it is easy, and compute the limits.  This shows you have a Cauchy sequence.  Your "new idea" is confused.  $f(x)$ cannot depend on $n$.

Comment: The intergral is just $2\sqrt{x}$ so its $2$ when $x=1$ and  $ 0 $ when $x=0$, which isn't in R[0,1] at the limit $1$. Are you saying what I put earlier isn't right to show it's Cauchy?